# Why does server fail with "java.net.SocketException: invalid argument" upon server's startup?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka **0.8**

I follow the quickstart guide and when I come to the Step 2 to run `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` I'm facing the exception:

```
[2013-08-06 09:55:14,603] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2013-08-06 09:55:14,657] ERROR Error while electing or becoming leader on broker 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
java.net.SocketException: invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:639)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(BlockingChannel.scala:57)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager.kafka$controller$ControllerChannelManager$$addNewBroker(ControllerChannelManager.scala:84)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager$$anonfun$1.apply(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager$$anonfun$1.apply(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:81)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager.<init>(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startChannelManager(KafkaController.scala:503)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.initializeControllerContext(KafkaController.scala:467)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:215)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:89)
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:53)
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener.handleDataDeleted(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:106)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$6.run(ZkClient.java:549)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread.run(ZkEventThread.java:71)
```

What could I be doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely to be either a problem with name resolution, or with leftover settings from 0.7.

If you are migrating from 0.7, see the [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Migrating+from+0.7+to+0.8).

If you're starting fresh, ensure that there is an *accurate* entry in /etc/hosts for your hostname.

e.g. given a `/etc/hostname` file with

```
yourhostname
```

and an interface (`/sbin/ifconfig`) listening with an example IP of `10.181.11.14`

/etc/hosts should correctly map that name to the listening interface:

```
10.181.11.14    yourhostname.yourdomain.com       yourhostname   someotheralias
```

You can test it by telnetting to the kafka port and ensuring that there is no timeout:

```
telnet yourhostname.yourdomain.com 9092
Trying 10.181.11.14...
Connected to yourhostname.yourdomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```